# How to set not to open new web browser tab in vscode when running asp.net core api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

e.g

Every time i key `ctrl + f5` or `ctrl + shift + f5` to rerun asp.net core api project in vscode,it'll open a new tab.

I expect just restart program `without opening new tab`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a browser tab? or a VSCode tab?

Comment: @Dai , yes , a browser tabe , thanks i fix it

Comment: So if let’s say there are two tabs already open in browser. Tab1, tab2. So in which tab you want to launch? Or do you want to launch new instance of browser?

Comment: @viveknuna hi,i just want to not open any tab , because it's api project

Comment: Every kind of application shows you some kind of UI, prompt or form. Otherwise how would user know that’s its up and running

Comment: @vivek nuna just terminal like nodejs ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12729184/87493832-383f2f80-c680-11ea-8a43-d086493b8994.png)

Comment: @vivek or system could reuse one tab and create a new one

Comment: By default it’s open a new tab only

Comment: @vivek nuna too sad,because it's a little annoy in api project, and thanks for your communication with me,could u answer below?

Comment: By the way, what template type of your project is? Is this **web** api? Yes yes then how can you expect web without the browser?

Comment: yes web api,i use postman to call api

Comment: I suspect you are asking what would happen if  you use `"launchBrowser": false,` - I bet it going to just not launch browser...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's the answer he wants! Please put it down...

Comment: @JeremyThompson but they accepted another solution... so they solved they problem... and I found useful setting for me that I did not know I wanted... so everyone wins :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### updated : CLI version (recommand)

It can use `dotnet watch` to do it .

[image]

### visul studio code (op want to merge)

If you don't want any browser tab be created,you colud go to `.vscode\launch.json` remove `serverReadyAction` and it can deal the problem.
[image]

default json :

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            //Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
             "serverReadyAction": {
                 "action": "openExternally",
                 "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

just delete or mark `serverReadyAction` then system'll not open any web browerser tab

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            //Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            // "serverReadyAction": {
            //     "action": "openExternally",
            //     "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            //}
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

---

P.S

I test set `launchBrowser enabled false` but it not work,it'll still create new tab.

launchBrowser enabled false launch.json :

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": false    
            },            
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/ServerApp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            //Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

### Visual Studio Version :

Every kind of application shows you some kind of UI, prompt, or form. Otherwise, how would user know that’s its up and running.

By default, it’s open a new tab only.

Your project template itself is web API? then how can you expect the web without the browser?

**Update**: I tried setting the `launchBrowser` to `false` in launchSettings.json in Visual studio 2019, it’s launching like the below images.

```
"profiles": {
  "IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": false,
    "launchUrl": "default",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  }
```

You are setting `launchBrowser` to `false` in wrong way, you have to do like this `"launchBrowser": false`. Its working fine in Asp.Net Core 3.1 API.

You can see in the taskbar

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks lot , i upvote this , according the communication with u then i found a way to deal the problem

Comment: @Wei you only asked me to post the answer. The other solution looks more relevant to you

Comment: yes,it's helpful answer , but i don't know why `launchBrowser false ` can not work ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12729184/87495442-04fe9f80-c684-11ea-8378-aff5834d7747.png)

Comment: I got the point ... it's `visual studio` not `visual studio code`!  
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12729184/87497377-ffa35400-c687-11ea-8373-df91cb04db76.png)

Comment: @Wei  why are you unaccepting the answer again and again? I have invested my time in solving the issue

Comment: thanks lot, but you use `visual studio` not `visual studio code` not the question IDE

Comment: could u merge my answer to your answer and then i'll mark this answer, because u spent so many time on the qeustion.

Comment: Sorry, it’s ok. I’m not greedy enough

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any browser tab be created,you colud go to `.vscode\launch.json` remove `serverReadyAction` and it can deal the problem.
[image]

default json :

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            //Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
             "serverReadyAction": {
                 "action": "openExternally",
                 "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

just delete or mark `serverReadyAction` then system'll not open any web browerser tab

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            //Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            // "serverReadyAction": {
            //     "action": "openExternally",
            //     "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            //}
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

---

P.S

I test set `launchBrowser enabled false` but it not work,it'll still create new tab.

launchBrowser enabled false launch.json :

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": false    
            },            
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/ServerApp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            //Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after setting for vscode files and add to launch.json

```
{
  "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "build",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Parto.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/Parto.Web.dll",
  "args": [],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Parto.Web",
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  "launchBrowser": {
    "enabled": true,
    "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
    "windows": {
        "command": "cmd.exe",
        "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
    },
    "osx": {
        "command": "open"
    },
    "linux": {
        "command": "xdg-open"
    }
  },
  "serverReadyAction": {
    "action": "openExternally",
    "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
  },
  "env": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "sourceFileMap": {
    "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
  }
},
{
        "name": ".NET Core Launch - Chrome",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Parto.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/Parto.Web.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Parto.Web",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start \"\" \"C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe\" ${auto-detect-url}"
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
            "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5000"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Parto.Web/Views"
        }
},
```

and settings.json

```
{
"omnisharp.path": "latest",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"[csharp]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
}
```

}

and add this to omnisharp.json

```
"MSBuild": {
"UseLegacySdkResolver": true}
```

in VS Code terminal

First dotnet build

Second dotnet run "Address of Web Project"

then after run project successfully

Launching browser by cmd.exe /C start http://localhost:5000